# Eclipse refactor Iterator/while to foreach

Tags: java, eclipse

Does anyone knows if there is a simple way of refactoring the code to use a foreach to iterate over a collection instead of a while/Iterator combo?

Example:

I have:

```
Iterator<MyObject> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   MyObject myObject = iterator.next();
   // do stuff
}
```

And I want:

```
for (MyObject myObject : list) {
   // do stuff
}
```

And yes, I understand I won't get any performance improvements. I just want it to be less verbose and because I fancy to :)

Comment: ***a simple way of refactoring the code ...***  just replace one snippet by the other...

Comment: A **simpler** way of refactoring the code, instead of doing a monkey job :)

Comment: What do you mean by refactoring? Do you mean automating the replacement in every file in your source code thus not doing it manually?

Comment: [Yep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)

Comment: Code refactoring does not inherently mean automated refactoring.  I'm pretty sure where he was going with that was that you could easily manually refactor the code.  Anyway, after taking a cursory look through the Eclipse Code Style settings (Window - Preferences - Java - Code Style), I'm pretty sure that the default Eclipse refactoring tools won't do this for you.  You could write an Eclipse plug-in, if you view that as less monkey work and a worthwhile time investment.

Comment: It is interesting that Eclipse can convert the `for (MyObject mo : list)` to either a indexed for loop or an iterator, but not the inverse. As @Ironcache just mentioned, you could write a quick assist to help.

Comment: ItelliJ has an automatic refactoring to convert to for loops. If you have the option I would check it out.

Comment: Exactly, I'm downloading IntelliJ right now

Comment: Also, I don't think working with all the hell that eclipse plugin development is would be a **simpler** alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose all the occurrence of the iteration code is similar to your example,
try using find and replace with following regular expression.

Find:

```
Iterator<([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,})> [a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,} = ([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,})\.iterator\(\);\R[\t]{1,}while \(iterator\.hasNext\(\)\) \{\R[\t]{1,}[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,} ([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}) = iterator\.next\(\);
```

Replace:

```
for($1 $3 : $2) {
```